# Recently used `MutationObserver` on github.com to monitor node change failure

Tags: github, mutation-observers

Last few days using `MutationObserver` on github.com site to monitor node changes intermittent failure.

Demo:

any gist url: https://gist.github.com/maboloshi/a4b1f27567319d4a42352aadd036a578

When you click on `Revisions`, the alert dialog box does not pop up

Demo Code:

```js
const m =
        window.MutationObserver ||
        window.WebKitMutationObserver ||
        window.MozMutationObserver;

new m(function(mutations) {
    alert('Monitor to page title change');
}).observe(
    document.querySelector('title'),
     { childList: true }
);
```

Comment: The site removes the `title` node and adds a new one, so you need to observe document.head.

Comment: @wOxxOm I found that monitoring `document.body` is also invalid.

Comment: It is possible that `github.com` currently has a mechanism for rewriting and directly rebuilding `document.body`.

Comment: I said `document.head` not `body`.